# AWS dynamodb scan returning multiple rows for the same hash key in a hash only table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Dynamodb table 'UserProfile' has a hash key called "UserId" and no range key. It has no indexes. I wanted to get all the data stored in the table using scan. Did this:

```
aws dynamodb scan --region "ap-southeast-1" --attributes-to-get "UserId" "details" --table-name UserProfile | less
```

And this returns many rows for the same userid. This is not expected. Thoughts on what could be wrong? I have looked through many documents related to dynamodb scans and not finding anything. Could it be that scan is giving me all versions of this data? If yes, how do i get only the latest snapshot?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: is this issue reproducible? Also for the multiple rows returned with same userId, I am wondering if those rows have the same data?

Comment: When you view the data via the AWS DynamoDB console is it correct?